# PHP $_POST does not work

Tags: php, mysql, post

```
foreach( $stmt as $row )
{

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><button type=button' disabled id='NameButton' name='NameButton' value='".$row['Name']."'>".$row['Name']."</button></td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['Level'] . "</td>";
    //echo "<td>" .$row[''] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" .$row['FirstName'] . " " .$row['LastName']. "</td>";
    echo "<td> <button id='editClass' name='editClass' value='".$row['ID']."'>რედაქტირება</button>  </td>";
    echo "<td> <button id='deleteClass'>წაშლა</button>   </td>";    
    echo "</tr>";

}
```

This is my code for displaying from DB . now I try to do edit for, and i need to get 2 values from this `form (1 => Name , 2 => Button [with ID from DB] )` for Button it works fine`( i post date )`  , but for button with value from DB Post does not work

```
$ID     =$_POST['editClass'];
$name   =$_POST['NameButton'];
$date=array(":ID"=>$ID ,":Name"=>$name);
var_dump($date);`
```

this is how i try to get date ... output for var_dump is :

```
array (size=2)
:ID' => string '132' (length=3)
:Name' => null
```

Comment: Please make your question legible.

Comment: You should be using `htmlspecialchars()` around any variable data used in the context of HTML, to avoid generating invalid ambiguous HTML and some XSS attacks.

Comment: Madbreaks why i get @date array not full ?

Comment: `type="button"` does not work for POST `type="submit"` does. Also, make sure your form contains a post method.

Comment: Multiple fields with the same name and duplicate ID's are going to get you into trouble.

Comment: `type=button'` is missing a single quote

Comment: You also need form tags, which no one can be sure if you have them or not.

Comment: Fred i have form tag with method="post" and action="*.php"

Comment: Change `<button type=button' disabled id='NameButton'` to `<button type='submit' disabled id='NameButton'` - you also had a missing quote, but even with the added quote, it would not have worked. POST methods with `type/button` do not work, it must be `type/submit`. @Boy-FromGalactic you may even need to remove `disabled` if required.

Comment: So, are you making any progress?

Comment: fred i did it , progress good , i send date , but now its not correct : as u see i use foreach( $stmt as $row ) to operate over query result ... and echoing date in table tag . 
so i try to do Edit Button work , because i got one-to-many relation , i have to check date for ID(its key from some other table in db ) , and Name /// 
ex : as i hit edit : incorect output is
'array (size=2)
  ':ID' => string '113' (length=3)
  'Name' => string '12-b' (length=4)
boolean false'
correct :
array (size=2)
  ':ID' => string '113' (length=3)
  'Name' => string '6-b' (length=4)
int 1

Comment: This is hard to read but try doing a var_dump or print_r of the $_POST variable.  That will show you everything that you're passing in to your page.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything. Plus, since you seem to be using PDO, add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, replacing `$pdo` with your DB variable connection. Also, `['Name']` is not the same as `['name']` should your column be called that. Plus, make sure your form's element is named, i.e.: `name="NameButton"`

Answer (score 0):

The button will not be submitted and it isn't designed for send data like inputs. Change the button tag for an input with submit's type.